# How to capture command line input into logfile and execute it at the same time?

Tags: bash, command-line, logs, command-history

Let's say I issue some commands on the command line:

```
#capture what follows
$ echo "foo"
foo

# don't capture
$ echo "bing"
bing

# capture again
$ echo "bar"
bar
```

How can I log commands **selectively** to a logfile, which **only** captures **the commands** themselves issued on the cli? 
I.e. effectively achieving something similar to `.bash_history`, but only for certain commands:

```
$ cat command.log
echo "foo"
echo "bar"
```

Note that **ouput** to `STDOUT` of each command should **not** be logged.
I've looked at [IO redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), but could not figure out a working solution.

Comment: You say "selectively". What is the selection criteria? Are you fine with manually typing a few extra characters for every command you want to log?

Comment: yes, that would be fine.

Comment: @jottr, you could try something as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21717593/1742825).

Comment: I've improved my question to clarify what I want.

Comment: @Ramesh, `script` logs STDOUT as well. That's an undesired effect.

Comment: Why not set `HISTFILE` to your log for the session, effectively logging the commands to that file?

Comment: I would prefer a solution that works in a oneliner. I.e. allowing me to quickly adding a command to `command.log`, something similar to IO redirection, but instead of `echo "foo" > output.log` I would like to somehow be able to log the command line to that logfile.

Comment: @jottr, please see the updates.

Comment: @Ramesh. Thx for your edited answer, but installing screen and using HISTFILE produces too much overhead.   
There must be a simpler solution out there.

Comment: @jottr The least clunky method I can come up with at the moment is to make an alias like `alias loglast='fc -ln -1 | cut -c 3- > ~/command.log'`, and then just run `loglast` after every command you want to log.

Comment: @jw013 thats way more elegant and at first sight might achieve what I need for my purpose.

Comment: @jw013 is there anything that makes it undesirable to write your suggested alias as a function? This would allow the user to pass a logfile as a parameter. 
Would you mind writing a proper answer, I would like to make your suggestion the accepted answer. thx

Comment: @jottr Yes, functions can do just about everything an alias can. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @jottr Another question. Would bash history work for you or do you want this selective logging in addition to normal bash history (i.e. logged commands should go to both .bash_history and the other log file).

Comment: @jw013 That doesn't really matter. What I mainly need is a means to store certain commands of my commandhistory to a file for later reference. Whether or not they are logged to .bash_history is not relevant to my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define a function like

```
loglast() {
    fc -ln -1 | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' >> "${1:-${logfile:-~/command.log}}"
}
```

then after every command you want to log, you can run `loglast` to log the previous command.

The log file used is (in order): the optional first argument to `loglast`, or `$logfile` if no argument given, or `$HOME/command.log` as a last default.

The `sed -s '/^[[:space:]]*//` removes the leading spaces that `fc` adds.

Comment: Easily support a selection argument like `fc` itself: `loglast () { fc -ln ${1:--1} ${2:--1} ...` which defaults to the one most recent command. To log only the 3rd most recent command, for example: `loglast -3 -3` Bind it to a keystroke by adding this to your `~/.inputrc` file: `"\e\C-l": "loglast\n"` which will allow you to log the most recent command by simply pressing `Ctrl-Alt-l` (the letter ell). Using the `.inputrc` file, the `loglast` command itself will be logged in Bash history when the keystroke is used. To avoid that, use `bind -x '"\e\C-l": "loglast"'` in your `~/.bashrc` instead.

Comment: Neat. Thx @DennisWilliamson

Comment: The `HISTIGNORE` approach is super simple. But the reason I like this answer is because you can retroactively log a command. Very handy if you're running commands and not sure of a successful outcome.

Comment: This is helpful way than HISTCONTROL, for host where developers don't have home directory like production hosts.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest approach is to use the functionality already provided by bash. Specifically, the `HISTIGNORE` variable:

```
   HISTCONTROL
          A  colon-separated  list  of values controlling how commands are
          saved on the history list.   If  the  list  of  values  includes
          ignorespace,  lines  which  begin with a space character are not
          saved in the history list.
```

So, you could do something as simple as

```
$ HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

Then, any commands you enter with a leading space will be ignored:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
$ history -c            ## clear previous history for this session
$ echo foo
foo
$   echo bar
bar
$ history 
1  echo foo
2  history
```

As you can see above, the command that started with a space was ignored.

---

You could also use `HISTIGNORE`:

```
    HISTIGNORE
          A colon-separated list of patterns used to decide which  command
          lines  should  be  saved  on  the history list.  Each pattern is
          anchored at the beginning of the line and must  match  the  com‐
          plete  line  (no  implicit  `*'  is  appended).  Each pattern is
          tested against the line after the checks specified  by  HISTCON‐
          TROL  are  applied.   In  addition  to  the normal shell pattern
          matching characters, `&' matches the previous history line.  `&'
          may  be  escaped  using  a  backslash;  the backslash is removed
          before attempting a match.  The second and subsequent lines of a
          multi-line compound command are not tested, and are added to the
          history regardless of the value of HISTIGNORE.
```

If you set `HISTIGNORE` to something like `#foo` and then append that to commands you want ignored, you can get the same effect:

```
$ HISTIGNORE="*#foo"
$ history -c  
$ echo foo
foo
$ echo "bar" #foo
bar
$ history 
1  echo foo
2  history
```

---

In both cases, if you want to save this to a file, just run `history > file`. Alternatively, set the history file to `file` for the session:

```
$ HISTFILE="/tmp/file"
$ HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
$ history -c
$ echo foo
foo
$   echo bar
bar
$ history -a   ## write the session's history to $HISTFILE
$ cat /tmp/file 
echo foo
history -a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `script` command:

```
script -f filename.log
```

It starts a new session and logs all your commands. When you exit the file is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of `script` command to log the commands. But this has the disadvantage of logging everything that you got in the standard output as well.

```
script -a #Start your scripting session. 

Script started, file is typescript
echo "Hello"
Hello
echo "Another Hello"
Another Hello
#Press Ctrl - D to exit the scripting session. 

Script done, file is typescript
```

Now, whatever you did in your session is logged in the *typescript* file.

```
cat typescript
Script started on Fri 21 Nov 2014 10:12:56 AM CST
echo "Hello"
Hello
echo "Another Hello"
Another Hello

Script done on Fri 21 Nov 2014 10:13:08 AM CST
```

**EDIT**

However, since you need to log only the commands rather than the output of the commands you could do something as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21717593/1742825).

1. If you do not have `screen`, install it using `apt-get install screen`.
2. Now, add the below contents to the file `~/.screenrc` (Even if the
   file doesn't exist you can create it).

   ```
   screen -t "window 0" 0 bash -ic 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.${WINDOW} bash'
   screen -t "window 1" 1 bash -ic 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.${WINDOW} bash'
   screen -t "window 2" bash -ic 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.${WINDOW} bash'
   bind c screen bash -ic 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.${WINDOW} bash'
   bind ^C screen bash -ic 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history.${WINDOW} bash'
   ```
3. Now, start your session by typing `screen` command and execute your
   commands as you normally would.
4. Now, you could view the list of the commands you used in the `screen` by checking the file `~/.bash_history.${WINDOW}` where `${WINDOW}` corresponds to the screen number in which you executed your commands.

Comment: Thx @Ramesh, but output should not be logged.